Can we *really* do algebraic operations involving roots on C?
With BSc in Maths and loads of grey hair, something has been on my mind for decades, and I couldn't quite enunciate it. Let me try.
Root is inherently "multi-valued" operation. So
$$
\sqrt{4} = \{2, -2\}
$$
Also, I understand that there's no definite way to order those roots. So if we add another root to it, we'll get all the permutations.
$$
\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{9} = \{2, -2\} + \{3, -3\} = \{5, 1, -1, -5\}
$$
But then won't we have
$$
\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4} = \{2, -2\} + \{2, -2\} = \{4, 0, -4\}
$$
Which doesn't make much sense, since we can simplify expression before extracting the root.
$$
\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4} = 2*\sqrt{4} = \{4, -4\}
$$
So, it seems that doing any algebra with roots only make sense if we stick with positive real numbers, otherwise, current algebraic notation is insufficiently unambiguous to deal with root expressions.
Appears like there's no way to algebraically express the difference between
$$
\sqrt{a*a} + \sqrt{b*b} = \{a, -a\} + \{b, -b\} = \{a+b, a-b, -a+b, -a-b\}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{a*a} + \sqrt{b*b} = \{a, -a\} + \{b, -b\} = \{a+b, -a-b\}
$$
Operator ± seems to be of no use either.
Am I missing something absolutely trivial?

What you write about $\sqrt{4}$ isn't correct - the more or less universal usage of $\sqrt{r}$ (for a nonnegative real r) is that it refers to the unique nonnegative square root of r.

When you wrote that $\sqrt4=[-2,2]$, did you mean to write that $\sqrt4={-2,2}$? Are you aware of the fact that $[-2,2]={x\in\Bbb R\mid-2\leqslant x\leqslant2}$?

Yeah, it refers to the positive root by default. That's just by definition

Thanks, Jose, updated, my latex is a bit rusty, didn't realise you can do "{" with "\ {"

Alan - sure, but then what would be the correct notation if we want to use ALL of the roots? ±?

Matthew - sure, but in cubic formula it's used like that.

The way the cubic formula is usually written with radicals is very imprecise. You can't make arbitrary choices of square roots and cube roots everywhere in the formula and expect to get a solution to the cubic, because that would be too many solutions. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311605/about-cardanos-formula-and-the-cubic-equation/2311626

Thanks Ted, that's exactly what I was wondering about.

If $A$ and $B$ are sets of real numbers (or complex numbers or vectors or anything else with a $+$ operation defined), we can define $A + B = \{ a + b : a \in A, b \in B \}$. (In some contexts, this is called the Minkowski sum.) But as you observed, it won't be true that $A + A = 2A = \{2a : a \in A\}$.  That's just the way it is.

Honestly, $a^b$ is (almost always) an ambiguous notation, although we all have internalized multiple sets of context clues that influence which answer is appropriate.
To give an extremely basic example: Is $8^{1/3}$:
$$ 2$$
or $$2, -1+\sqrt 3 i, -1-\sqrt 3 i$$
(where in this case $\sqrt 3$ represents the single positive real number that squares to $3$)?
Being in a 9th grade math class vs. being in a complex analysis course would push you strongly towards one versus the other, but without someone pointing you towards which was intended you cannot be certain, and there's no existing notation that, just by itself, unambiguously clarifies this.
I would say that in the examples you've given, there is a very strong context push towards "unique nonnegative square root of r", as MatthewTowers commented, and as I made explicit in my example.
To further bang the drum about context, when you were doing your math degree, did you think that "$1+\sqrt2 i$" referred to two different numbers? Probably not.

I disagree here. For $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ the default meaning of $a^b$ unless something is explicitly stated otherwise is the positive real value of that expression; i.e., $e^{b\ln a}$ where we take the real value of the logarithm rather than any of the complex branch values. Just because there are multiple values that can be assigned to the expression doesn't mean that there are multiple values 'for' the expression.

I'd say that "$a \in \mathbb R^+$" qualifies as context.

Except that in your answer, $8\in\mathbb{R}^+$.  That is the unambiguous clarification, absent a specific statement to the contrary.

I mean, yes, we often assume the simplest answer possible. That's an assumption, and I'm pretty sure I had homework problems when first learning about complex numbers that said "List all the values of $8^{1/3}$, and I think we're doing students a disservice when we pretend that there are clear disambiguation rules, instead of teaching them to demand clarification.
